# react state not updated even inside callback

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm having problem setting state. I've to pass extra classes to `CardComponent` on click, on click is working fine, `setState` is called, and the `callback` executes, but state is not mutated (as logs clearly deny that state is updated - see `onSelect` below). How could I fix that?

Flow is that if an item is selected, parent component resets the array with selected property set on each item (the selected result object gets `selected` set to `true`), that works fine and list is reset, selected is highlighted. Then if user clicks on another item (SearchResult component), it should update itself and apply extra classes. This time it's guarenteed that parent would not reset the list.

```
import { Component, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";
import CardComponent from "../../utils/card.component";

export interface SearchResultComponentClickEvent {
  (_id: string): void;
}

export interface SearchResultComponentProps {
  result: any;
  full: boolean;
  onClick: SearchResultComponentClickEvent;
  onSelect: Subject<string>;
}

interface SearchResultComponentState {
  selected: string;
  extraClasses: string;
}

export default class SearchResult extends Component<
  SearchResultComponentProps,
  SearchResultComponentState
> {
  onSelectSubscription: Subscription = null;

  constructor(props: SearchResultComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    let extraClasses = "mb-4";
    if (this.props.result.selected) extraClasses += " border border-primary";

    this.state = {
      selected: this.props.result.selected,
      extraClasses,
    };

    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.onSelectSubscription = this.props.onSelect.subscribe((_id: string) => {
      this.setState({
        selected: '',
        extraClasses: 'mb-4'
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this.onSelectSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSelect() {
    this.setState({
      selected: this.props.result._id,
      extraClasses: "mb-4 border border-primary",
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
      // logs: { selected: '', extraClasses: "mb4 " }
    });

    this.props.onClick(this.props.result._id);
  }

  view(): ReactNode {
    return <div>Simple view</div>
  }

  fullView(): ReactNode {
    return <div>Extended view</div>;
  }

  render(): ReactNode {
    return (
      <CardComponent
        padding={0}
        onClick={this.onSelect}
        extraClasses={this.state.extraClasses}
        key={this.state.extraClasses}
      >
        {this.props.full ? this.fullView() : this.view()}
      </CardComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `CardComponent` component look like? I.e. how is it using the `extraClasses` prop?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the state but setState is asynchronous in nature, changing the state will not immediately give its updated value https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate, if you can show snippet of what exactly are you doing CardComponent, can give a more reliable solution.
If you still want to go with this approach, you can change your onSelect to something like this.

```
onSelect() {
    this.setState({
      selected: this.props.result._id,
      extraClasses: "mb-4 border border-primary",
    }, function() { 
         console.log(this.state);
         this.props.onClick(this.props.result._id);
       });
  }
```

this will wrap or attached a callback to the state, which guarantees it, but it has its own side effects.
I would also recommend `componentDidUpdate` over this solution, more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the **rxjs Subscription** object.
Insert console.log and check...

```
componentDidMount(): void {
  this.onSelectSubscription = this.props.onSelect.subscribe((_id: string) => {
    // Log
    console.log('componentDidMount-onSelectSubscription', this.state);

    this.setState({
      selected: '',
      extraClasses: 'mb-4'
    });
  });
}
```